# Connect to ASE sybase in Robotframework

Tags: robotframework, sap-ase

I am trying to connect to ASE sybase using below but cannot:

```
connect To Database Using Custom Params    pyodbc     "Driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise}; server=; port=;db=;uid=; pwd=;"
```

I have installed "pyodbc" using ‘pip install pyodbc’.

Comment: Those quotes look out of place around the whole connection string. I doubt you need them. Also, you're probably not going to have much luck if you don't define at least a server and port. Robot isn't a shell, so you don't need to quote arguments to keywords. You are probably getting an error, please include that error in your question.

Comment: With the quotes it worked. As the server, port ,db , user, passwd have to be provided and hence those have been simply put as empty with only those fields. It has to be understood that those should be provided.

In robot framework you have to provide the arguments to keywords. The arguments may be default and non-default ones.That would help to re-use keywords. For more details refer to the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788795/how-to-use-user-keyword-arguments-with-default-values-in-robotframework

Comment: I know how keywords work - I have the highest robotframework rep on stackoverflow. Your comment is unclear. The question shows using quotes and claims it doesn't work, but your comment says "with the quotes it worked". Does that mean you have solved your problem?

Comment: Yes. I got it solved. I was missing the installation as commented by @Nikesh

Comment: Yes. Problem has been solved. @bryan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are getting error something like - ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Its probably your installation is no complete - Follow below steps

Install -

I:\Apps\Sybase_OpenClient_15.5_0_ESD8x64_DTP_v1.0\Sybase_OpenClient_15.5_0_ESD8x64_DTP_v1.0.msi

Insure environment variables/PATH is set

This should work.